# duplicate dynamic dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have a dynamic dropdown list. And i want to duplicate it but it is not working well.
Here is my code.
My code works well with getting the option values from the database but it wont duplicate.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="input-group"><label for="type">Type<br/></label>
    <select id="type">
    <option value="">Select Item</option>
    <?php 
    echo load_item(); 
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // copy the select area
    $('#type').clone().attr('id', 'type1').attr('name', 'type1').appendTo($('#div2'));

    // make the current value selected
    $("#type1 > option[value='" + $('#type').val() + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');

});
```

And here is how i get the option values

```
function load_item(){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "atos");
    $output = ''; 
    $sql = "SELECT item_type_id,item_type FROM item_tbl";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
            $output .='<option value="'.$rows["item_type_id"].'">'.$rows["item_type"].'</option>';
            }
    return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make an exact replica of the dropdown? If so, `document.getElementById("type").innerHTML` should be all you need. Then just encase it in select tags and place it wherever you need.

Comment: im sorry ive tried my code again and its working fine now, but my problem is i want to make it using the add button and duplicate it as many as i want.

Comment: like type1 type2 type3 type4 is it possible?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, you just have to write the javascript to do so

Comment: var i=0;
$('.addNew').click(function (){
    i++;
    // copy the select area
    $('#type').clone().attr('id', 'type'+i+'').attr('name', 'type'+i+'').appendTo($('#div2'));
    
    // make the current value selected
    $("#type+i+ > option[value='" + $('#type').val() + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');

});

Comment: Ive tried this one and it works fine now. Thanks. :))